# Common use of character 大 as adverb

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, adverbs

Wenlin dictionary doesn't consider 大 as an adverb, whereas Online dictionary [Chine Nouvelle](https://chine-nouvelle.com/outils/dictionnaire.html) considers it also as an adverb.

So is 大 commonly used in modern Chinese as an adverb? Or would it not be grammatically correct to translate 大 as "greatly"?

What about the use of the structural particle 地 (de) after the adjective to make it function as an adverb concerning 大?

Answer (score 4):

Besides being a common adjective, 大 is also a common adverb. It is mostly used with single character verb or adjective (more literary than colloquial)

Example:

- 駡 (to scold) --> 大駡 (to scold strongly) e.g. 大駡他是漢奸
- 好 (good) --> 大好 (quite good; very good) e.g. 現在形勢大好
- 讚 (to praise) --> 大讚 (to greatly praise) e.g. 大讚他品學兼優
- 勇 (strong) --> 大勇 (very stong) e.g. 這匹馬狀態大勇

We can use 地 with 大 when 大 is reduplicated. For Example, 大大地提高 (greatly raise)， 大大地增加(greatly increase). But 地 is optional, meaning without it, the adverb still works, e.g. 大大提高，大大增加

We never use the adverb marker 地 with 大 alone. 大地提高 or 大地增加 is ungrammatical

大 in 大地 (the earth) is an adjective and 大地 itself is a compound word noun

Comment: Also, 大 大 小 小 is a ......... ?

Comment: @Wayne Cheah 大大小小的 (big and small) is an adjective.  e.g. 大大小小的獎項; 大大小小的工程. (大大的 + 小小的 = 大大小小的)

Answer (score 3):

Very good answer from Tang Ho. I'd just like to add a few 4-character expressions that use 大 as adverb:

大吃一驚 to be greatly surprise/ shocked

大灑金錢 to spend a lot of money

大興土木 to build many things (literally, to move earth and wood)

Example sentence:

這個政府忽然大灑金錢，大興土木，建了很多無用的設施，令人大吃一驚。

Out of the blue, this government spent a lot of money to build many useless facilities. This really shocked a lot of people.

These are just a few expressions that came to mind. I am sure there are many more.

Comment: 政客們不但大放厥词，還大打出手，真是大失民心 The politicians not only freely speaking non-sense,  they also ferociously fist fought each other, which greatly disappointed the people.

Comment: 人民只好大嘆倒霉，希望下次大選的時候可以大換血，就大快人心了！ The common people will have to resign to their ill fate. Hopefully when election (大選) comes next time, there will be a complete change of people, then people will say, Good riddance! (大換血 = complete blood transfusion). We are having fun with this, aren't we?

Comment: 在大大小小的大选中，有大多数是大骗局。所以，不是大换血，而是换来更大的吸血大魔鬼. (In elections, big & small, most of them are fraudulent. So, it is not a complete blood transfusion, but a transfusion of an even bigger blood-sucking monster)